# PHP - IRC Connection

Tags: php, irc

Here is my script:

```
$ircServer = "";
$ircPort = "6667";
$ircChannel = "#";

set_time_limit(0);

$ircSocket = fsockopen($ircServer, $ircPort, $eN, $eS);

if ($ircSocket) {

    fwrite($ircSocket, "USER Lost rawr.test lol :code\n");
    fwrite($ircSocket, "NICK Rawr" . rand() . "\n");
    fwrite($ircSocket, "JOIN " . $ircChannel . "\n");

    while(1) {
        while($data = fgets($ircSocket, 128)) {
            echo nl2br($data);
            flush();

            // Separate all data
            $exData = explode(' ', $data);

            // Send PONG back to the server
            if($exData[0] == "PING") {
                fwrite($ircSocket, "PONG ".$exData[1]."\n");
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo $eS . ": " . $eN;
}
```

I am having problem's adding a function that will Private message everyone on the IRC channel. I tried $read and other methods it does not work and IRC hangs.

NOTE: This is for educational/private purposes no harm is done or made.

Comment: I feel like any IRC bot that private messages everybody in a channel is bad news bears. Raymond: I feel like you should post the intended use, as this could be used for great evil.

Comment: Nope, its for private use my friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've written several IRC bots years ago in Perl, and to be honest, I can't remember them anymore. Anyway, to send a private message to all the users, first you need to get all the users in the channel.

Anyway, the command to send a private message is:

```
PRIVMSG #channel :Sup?
```

Yeah, it will echo "Sup?" at the #channel. Then same goes for a user:

```
PRIVMSG John :Sup?
```

All you need to do is get all the users. To do this:

```
NAMES #channel
```

The code is up to you. Good luck.

**EDIT**: To get a percentage of the users, simply load them in an array, then use [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) `shuffle($array);` if you want to randomize their positions. Then use [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) `$size = count($array);` for the array size, multiply the size by the percentage. `$target = $size * 0.10;` for 10%. Then use [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) to get the rounded-off number.

Now, loop the array of users and set the limit to `$target`. There you have it.

**EDIT**: Here's a sample code (the rest of the code is up to you ofc:

```
...

$msg = $_POST['message'];
$pr = $_POST['percentage'];
$pr /= $100; // if the input is already 0.10 or something, no need to do this.

...

shuffle($users);
$size = count($users);
$target = $size * $pr;
$target = $round($target);

for ($i = 0; $i <= $target; $i++) {
    fwrite($ircSocket, "PRIVMSG " . $users[$i] . " :" . $msg . "\n")
}

...
```

Comment: Nice, how would I randomly grab a % percentage of the users on the channel and private message them? (PHP Form).

Comment: Ruel, I think you have misunderstood. Sorry to not make it clear. I need the PHP script to randomly select a % of users on the IRC channel and private messaging them "Hello".

Comment: Bascailly posting data in a HTML/PHP Form and sending the message to a % of random users on the IRC channel.

Comment: I do understand you. :) I've already explained the details how to do that. `shuffle()` randomizes the array, and the other part of my explanation gets a percentage of it. I'll edit my answer again to show you a sample code.

Comment: Basically, the PHP should connect to the IRC. A HTML Form or PHP Form will appear "I enter hello" into the form it should private message a % of random users on the IRC Channel. It's like rotating the users on the channel. All done by PHP/HTML.

Comment: Thanks, I'll co struct it into my script later. I only knew how to select percentage via php to mysql.